# Input feature mask name with variable - error 865

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, iteration, extract-by-mask, environment-variable

I have 73 raster files, with 73 corresponding shapefiles. I have to extract each of these raster by their corresponding shapefiles. I tried to call the shapefile using %Name%, since it has the same name, but it gives me an error.

My shapefiles are from Thiessen Polygon, and in the end I have to build a mosaic with all these pieces of raster.

How do I solve this problem?

[image: model builder]

[image: shape files]

[image: raster files]

Comment: Is it possibly the '' that you have around the %Name% variable? Does the information on this page help? It may be that the inline variable is being referenced incorrectly (see Example 6 as a possibility?) https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm

Comment: I tried ' and " and It didn't work. About example 6, It seems to me that I am calling the right variable, which is Name...

Comment: Sorry I meant try writing it without any ' or " e.g. conv_Local_%Name%. In Example 6 I was wondering about the need to parse the Name in case it is trying to copy the entire filepath over again

Comment: Where is the connection to the shapefiles/feature classes in the extract by mask tool?

Comment: It's in conv_Local_%Name%.shp, but it can't reach the files